# Windows 8 - Start screen icon for IE launches desktop version of IE

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, internals

When I first installed Windows 8 (64 bit, Pro version, with Media Player), the IE icon on the Start screen launched the Metro / Modern / Windows Store / whatever version of IE.

But somewhere along the line, it no longer does so. It launches the traditional IE desktop version.

Any suggestions how to get things back to normal?

Side questions: I haven't done any spelunking on Windows 8. Any tips for the following questions would be appreciated...

- What are the relevant file locations for various "Metro" apps (both Microsoft and 3rd party)? I know about C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WinMetadata for .winmd files. C:\Windows\WinStore seems almost useless. What else is worthwhile looking at?
- Ditto for registry entries
- What's hidden where? I assume that apps have NTFS permissions set so that, even as an Administrator (and with doing a Takeown) I can't even see certain system/app-related things.
- Where is the Start Screen located? Suppose I wanted to write a program that lists the Start Screen icons, their captions, etc
- And any other internals info of this ilk would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Go to *Internet Options*, *Programs* tab and in the *Opening Internet Explorer* section disable the ckeckbox *Open Internet Explorer Tiles on the desktop*.

Greetings.